# Weird output when redirecting bash prompt to a file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, redirection

I redirected standard error of bash command to a file and bash prompt got redirected.
But when i print the content of file, it was empty. Where did the bash prompt go?

[image]

and again when i redirect stdout of bash to a file, it redirected the output and and not the prompt as expected but while printing the content of file, there were some characters form the prompt too. How?

[image]

value of $PS1 and $PROMPT_COMMAND:

[image]

Comment: For future reference, [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). The link leads to our sister site but the reasoning applies here as well.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. From now on i won't post image of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `bash 2>file` explained

Interactive Bash does use stderr to print the prompt (and the command line while it's being edited).

`bash 2>file` does not save any of these to the file because it's not interactive. Non-interactive `bash` does not print any prompt, does not evaluate `PROMPT_COMMAND`; there is no command line editing provided by `readline` and if the input is from the terminal then only basic editing provided by the terminal driver is available.

While Bash Reference Manual claims "an interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments […] and whose input and output are both connected to terminals […]", my tests indicate it's not about stdin and stdout (as I would interpret "input and output") but about stdin and stderr. I mean these start non-interactive shells:

- `<script bash`
- `bash 2>file`

and these start interactive shells:

- `bash >file`
- `bash`

With `bash 2> file` you started a non-interactive shell. `bash` did not print any prompt, that's why the file turned out to be empty.

If you did `bash -i 2>file` then you would enforce an interactive shell, you would send prompt(s) to the file. Try it, but expect no echo of what you type, because this goes to the file.

Similarly if you redirected stderr of already running interactive bash (`exec 2>file`) then you would also capture its prompt(s).

---

#### `bash >file` explained (in your case)

As stated above, `bash >file` starts an interactive shell. One sees prompts in the terminal, one can edit commands. Stdout is redirected as one expects.

In your case `file` contained extra strings because your `PROMPT_COMMAND` is what it is.

> `PROMPT_COMMAND`
> If this variable is set, and is an array, the value of each set element is interpreted as a command to execute before printing the primary prompt (`$PS1`). If this is set but not an array variable, its value is used as a command to execute instead.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND))</sup>

This is your `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

> ```
> printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"
> ```

When executed, it prints to stdout. If stdout is redirected to a file, it will print to the file.

When sent to a sufficiently advanced terminal (terminal emulator), a byte sequence resulted from `\033]0;…\007` changes icon name and window title. In other words normally your terminal intercepts this output and uses it to configure itself rather then printing anything.

Probably you had deliberately set this `PROMPT_COMMAND` and forgot (or wasn't aware in the first place) it prints to stdout.

When stdout is redirected to a regular file then there will be no terminal to intercept the sequence and what `printf` from `PROMPT_COMMAND` prints will get to the file. You observed exactly this. It seems `bat` tried to do something with the ESC characters (from `\033`), `]0;` and the first letter of `kapil`, that's why you saw `apil`; BEL characters resulting from `\007` were shown as [`^G`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation#Description). It doesn't matter. The point is what you didn't expect came from `printf` in your `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

If I were you and I wanted to keep this `PROMPT_COMMAND`, I would set it to `printf … >&2`. Normally stdout and stderr of an interactive shell go to the same terminal, so it doesn't matter which one `printf` (executed from `PROMPT_COMMAND`) prints to. But when you redirect stdout as you did, you don't want "garbage" from `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: +1. Good explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Superb explanation btw.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting will result in a file that is difficult to read
(or use) because of the binary characters in the prompt.

For getting a readable complete copy of your session, you could use
[script(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)
to log everything sent to the terminal:

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
$ # do your work
...
$ # then exit with ^D
$ exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

Comment: First paragraph isn't really correct as `bash`, in common with other shells, won't write a prompt at all unless it is running as an interactive instance. `script` works because it creates a pseudo tty (like `screen`) and sends output not only to the terminal but also the `typescript` file